# how access to TextView by its id in android?

Tags: java, android, textview

for example I have 10 Textiews with names text1 to text11 . I cast them such as below :

```
    TextView text1=(TextView) findViewByid(R.id.textview1);
```

and do it for remains. now in somewhere I want to invoke them and set text for them in for loop , for example when i=1 text1.settext done , when i=2 text2.settext done and ... such as below :

```
    for(int i=1;i<=11;i++){
        text(i).SetText("some text");
    }
```

how can do it ?

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try populating an `ArrayList` with your text views.

```
ArrayList<TextView> myTextViews = new ArrayList<TextView>();

myTextViews.Add((TextView) findViewByid(R.id.textview1));
myTextViews.Add((TextView) findViewByid(R.id.textview2));
.
.
.
 for(int i=1;i<=11;i++){
    myTextViews.get(i).SetText("some text");
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Another way to do this is to generate the text views with java:

```
 LinearLayout ll = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.llexample);
for(int i=1;i<=11;i++){
    TextView tv = new TextView(this);  //create Text View
    tv.setId(i);                       //then set the id to i
    ll.addView(tv);                    //add TV to example Layout
}
```

Then when you want to retrieve them just do another for loop with:

```
for(int i=1;i<=11;i++){
  TextView t = (TextView) findViewById(i); //get the TV by the id we set earlier
  String text = t.getText().toString(); //get the text then to string it.
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Simply use arrays to hold your TextViews by:

```
TextView[] text = {(TextView) findViewByid(R.id.textview1), ...}
```

Then use it in the loop:

```
for(int i=1;i<=11;i++){
        text[i].SetText("some text");
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

I haven't tested it out. But you can try something like this

```
public setAllText() {
    int[] textViews = { R.id.text1, R.id.text2, R.id.text3, R.id.text4 };
    setTextForViews(textViews,"some text");
}

private void setTextForViews(int[] textViews, String textString) {
    for (int i = 0; i < textViews.length; i++) {
        TextView text = (TextView) getActivity().findViewById(textViews[i]);
        text.setText(textString);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

use [ButterKnife](http://jakewharton.github.io/butterknife/) library:

```
@Bind({ R.id.first_name, R.id.middle_name, R.id.last_name })
List<EditText> nameViews;
```

Then you can set you own logic by doing this

```
static final ButterKnife.Action<View> DISABLE = new ButterKnife.Action<View>() {
  @Override public void apply(View view, int index) {
    view.setEnabled(false);
  }
};

ButterKnife.apply(nameViews, DISABLE);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get the value of a resource id using this method:

```
public static int getResourceId(String pVariableName, String pResourcename, String pPackageName) {
    try {
        return getResources().getIdentifier(pVariableName, pResourcename, pPackageName);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        return -1;
    } 
}
```

Then your code would look something like:

```
for(int i=1;i<=11;i++){
    TextView textView = (TextView)findViewById(getResourceId("textview" + i, "id", getPackageName());
    textView.setText("some text");
}
```

It's worth noting that this is not really a recommended practice, as it is error prone.  You don't really know that "textview1" exists so it could fail if you ever change that name.  If you could give me a bit more information about your use case, I can give you a more elegant solution.

Answer (score 0):

I'd say arrays like everyone ese, with one twist.

```
int ids[] ={R.id.text1, R.id.text2, ...};
TextView views[] = new TextView[ids.length];
int i=0;
for(int id : ids) {
   views[i++] = (TextView)findViewById(id);
}
```

Keeping the ids in an array makes for easily finding the views rather than copy pasting a lot of code.